# How to stop rotating map over navigation?? HERE iOS SDK

Tags: ios, dictionary, navigation, orientation, here-api

When driving straight forward on the road, the map always lean left and right randomly.

At the turn, the swing is more obvious.The direction of the vehicle sign is unstable.

We added marker at each coordinate of route's geometry, and we discovered every swing happen close to those points.

[iOS video added here link  with](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w9JcKIacXxuEQevLLTcXi6AkV3Gq0hHL/view?usp=sharing)

HERE SDK version: 3.13
self.navigationManager.mapTrackingEnabled = true
self.navigationManager.mapTrackingOrientation = .dynamic

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Many thanks.

Comment: This issue has been fixed, and will release at next HERE SDK version 3.14

Answer (score 0):

HERE SDK version 3.14 is available now on developer portal with the fix for the reported issue.